# Предикат для сравнения массива char

Tags: c++, сортировка, stl, char, предикат

Хочу отсортировать массив из массивов char (char[32]). Хочу использовать метод sort из stl. Если передавать только начало и конец массива, то происходит что-то странное и весь массив теряется.

[image: изображение]

Скорее всего нужно 3 параметром передать предикат для сравнения, но с моей реализацией выдает ошибку

```
bool mypred(char a[32], char b[32]) {
    int res = strcmp(a, b);
    if (res > 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

sort(begin(mas), end(mas), mypred);
```

Не знаю как правильно сделать. Ошибка: C2664    "bool (char [],char [])": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "_Ty" в "char []"

Код объявления массива:

```
   template<typename T>
    class Algorithm {
    public:
        virtual void Start() = 0;
    protected:
        int length;
        T* data;
    };
template<>
class QuickSort<char[32]> :public Algorithm<char[32]> {
public:
    QuickSort(int size) {
        this->length = size;
        this->data = new char[size][32];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            char a[32];
            a[0] = (char)((rand() % 33) + 90);
            a[1] = '\0';
            strcpy_s((this->data)[i], a);
        }
    }

    void Start() override {
        cout << "QuickSort " << typeid(*this->data).name() << " для " << this->length << endl;
        sort(this->data[0], this->data[length], mypred);
    }
```

Comment: Массив из массивов, говорите? `char [32]` больше похож на обычный массив.

Comment: Нет, у меня mas это массив из char[32]

Comment: То есть `char mas[32][N]?` Добавьте в вопрос определение массива. В идеале нужен [mcve].

Comment: добавил свой говнокод

Comment: И где же в вашем коде фактический вызов `std::sort`???

Comment: если в каждом массиве всего один символ, то зачем нужен массив массивов?..  Зачем скопировать один символ функцией  strcpy_s?  Или я что то не правильно понимаю?..

Comment: Там по заданию должно быть слово, но я не хочу забивать целое слово вручную, поэтому просто забиваю только один символ

Comment: И из за этого получаете ошибку.

Comment: В каждом массиве по одному символу, а вы хотите сортировать size символов, вот и теряете этот один символ тоже, он выскакивает из массива

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Независимо от типа элемента `T`, если у вас есть массив `T a[length]` (или указатель `T *a` на начало массива из `T` длины `length`), который вы хотите отсортировать при помощи `std::sort`, то правильный вызов `std::sort` будет иметь вид

  ```
  std::sort(a, a + length, ...)
  // эквивалентно
  // std::sort(&a[0], &a[length], ...)
  ```

  а не

  ```
  std::sort(a[0], a[length], ...)
  ```

  как у вас в коде. Тот вызов, который вы использовали у себя в коде на самом деле пытается сортировать `length` букв самой первой строки (`this->data[0]`). Это, очевидно, совсем не то, что вы хотели получить.
- Последовательности из голых обычных массивов невозможно сортировать через `std::sort`. Массив не удовлетворяет требованиям, налагаемым на элемент последовательности для `std::sort`: массивы некопируемы. Вы можете сортировать массив из элементов `std::array<char, 32>`, но не массив из голых `char [32]`.

  Классический `std::qsort` такое осилит. Но не `std::sort`.
- (Забыв на минутку о предыдущем пункте.) Предикат сравнения для `std::sort` обязан быть совместимым с *константными* значениями сортируемых элементов. Несмотря на то, что ваши элементы неконстантны, `std::sort` внутри себя может захотеть сделать вызов вашего предиката с константным аргументом.

  То есть с формальной точки зрения ваш предикат должен быть объявлен как

  ```
  bool mypred(const char a[32], char const b[32])
  // эквивалентно
  // bool mypred(const char *a, char const *b)
  ```

  или как

  ```
  bool mypred(const char (&a)[32], char const (&b)[32])
  ```
- Что это за

  ```
  if (res > 1)
  ```

  в предикате? Результат функции `strcmp` имеет только три состояния: отрицательное число, положительное число или `0`. Этот результат можно сравнивать с `0`, но  никакого осмысленного ветвления по `> 1` для этого результата быть не может.

Comment: Хорошо, если через sort нельзя, то как сделать по другому? Когда смотрел про qsort, уж больно там запутанно было, как по мне

Comment: @Mii: Просто используйте `std::array<char, 32>` вместо `char [32]`. И предикат свой перепишите на аргументы `const std::array<char, 32> &`.

Comment: а лучше  просто использовать массив или какой нибудь контейнер с обьектами  string и не заморачиваться